# What's an alternative to traits for selecting between two different named functions?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

And also ... I don't want to use function pointers, I really want to use the function itself directly (so it can be inlined or have other optimizations apply).

Suppose:  I've got a template function/class that is going to compute some mathematical stuff, and the template parameter is the integral type which might be `unsigned int32_t` or it might be `unsigned int64_t`.

At some point I'm going to need random numbers, so I need a generator, and in the one case I'm going to use `mt19937` and in the other `mt19937_64`.  So the actual type names are different, but I've got to pick one and actually write it in the source code.

Obviously a traits class on the integral type would work fine (and that's what I'm doing now).  But it seems to me rather heavyweight syntax-wise for this one-time use, and also somewhat non-local (w.r.t. reading the source code if you get what I mean).

Another approach would be to encapsulate the use of the generator inside some (generic) function and provide full specializations of it for my two integral types.  And that actually is ok.

But: Are there other alternatives?  Is there some kind of compile-time "if" or "switch" (not quite `enable-if` which enables/disables templates from instantiating) that I can use here?  Or something else (perhaps even simpler than template metaprogramming which I'm just not seeing)?

(P.S. Please don't get hung up on `mt19937` & `mt19937_64` - I know those are both aliases of a type I could instantiate myself with my integral type - but I'd much rather use the standard definitions with their large set of quite magic numbers.  Plus I'm not just interested in `mt19937`/`mt19937_64` but other similar cases as well.)

Here's what the code for my traits class currently looks like:

```
template <class Base>
struct traits { };

template <>
struct traits<unsigned __int32>
{
    using base_t = unsigned __int32;
    static const int nbits = std::numeric_limits<base_t>::digits;
    using random_engine_t = std::mt19937;
    ...
};

template <>
struct traits<unsigned __int64>
{
    using base_t = unsigned __int64;
    static const int nbits = std::numeric_limits<base_t>::digits;
    using random_engine_t = std::mt19937_64;
    ...
};
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using for traits.

Comment: What's wrong with the traits? Is it that you only need `traits<T>::random_engine_t` in exactly one spot so you don't like the boilerplate?

Comment: Pretty much, but also that the boilerplate is remote from the point-of-use.  Which means you've got to invent a name for the abstraction and remember it, instead of just using the two original names in-line/in-place where you want to use them.  (Surrounded of course, by some extra syntax, which is hopefully "reasonably easy to read" for some C++-relative value of "reasonable".)

Comment: You might be fearing function pointers for no good reason. If `foo(void(*))` is `inline`, calling `foo(&bar)` will allow the optimizer to inline `foo`, discover that _for that specific inlined instance_ the called function is always `bar`, and continue inlining.

Comment: @MSalters - good tip - I'll check that out in the generated assembly, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Approach #1: generate clean distributed traits types.

Some utilities:

```
template<class T>struct tag_t{using type=T;};
template<class T>constexpr tag_t<T> tag = {};
template<class Tag>using type=typename Tag::type;
```

Now, instead of traits classes, we create tagged overloads:

```
tag<std::mt1337> which_random_engine( tag_t<int> );
tag<std::mt1337_64> which_random_engine( tag_t<std::int64_t> );
```

which lets you do such overloading ... wherever.

We can use this to define a traits class:

```
template<class T>
using random_engine_for = type<decltype(which_random_engine(tag<T>))>;
```

Use:

```
random_engine_for<T> engine;
```

---

Approach #2:

```
template<class A, class B> struct zpair_t {};
template<class T, class...> struct lookup_t {};
template<class T, class A, class B, class...Ts>
struct lookup_t<T, zpair_t<A, B>, Ts...>:lookup_t<T, Ts...>{};
template<class T, class B, class...Ts>
struct lookup_t<T, zpair_t<T, B>, Ts...>:tag_t<B>{};
template<class T, class Default, class...Ts>
struct lookup_t<T, tag_t<Default>, Ts...>:tag_t<Default>{
  static_assert(sizeof(Ts...)==0, "Default must be last");
};

template<class A, class B> using kv=zpair_t<A,B>;
template<class Default> using otherwise=tag_t<Default>;
template<class T, class...KVs>
using lookup = type<lookup_t<T, KVs...>>;

using random_engine_t = 
  lookup< T,
    kv< int, std::mt19937 >,
    kv< std::int64_t, std::mt19937_64 >,
    otherwise<void> // optional
  >;
```

which uses some of the same utilities, and does a compile-time type map.

I'm sure `boost` has better variation on the syntax.

Comment: Basically the same syntax... `mpl::pair` instead of `zpair`, `mpl::at<mpl::map<pairs...>, T>` instead of `lookup<T, pairs...>`.

Comment: The tag approach is very cool and I'm very comfortable with tag dispatch.  Didn't know it could be packaged up so easily.  I'll compare and contrast with `std::conditional` now.

Comment: Oh and BTW also thank you for reminding me of alias templates, very useful here as well.

Comment: Note that approach#1 needs `tag_t<std::mt19937>` as return value of `which_random_engine` to compile.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```
template <class Int>
using engine_t = std::conditional_t<
    std::is_same<Int, uint32_t>{},
    std::mt19937,
    std::mt19937_64
>;
```

Assuming that `Int` can only be `uint32_t` or `uint64_t`. This gets steadily more complicated the more types you end up with. Also it has safety issues - what if now `uint16_t` is supported? You'd end up silently using `mt19937_64` which is probably not the right decision.

---

You could also use the [`mpl::map`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/map.html) approach:

```
using engine_map = mpl::map<
    mpl::pair<uint32_t, std::mt19937>,
    mpl::pair<uint64_t, std::mt19937_64>
>;

template <class Int>
using engine_t = typename mpl::at<engine_map, Int>::type;
```

This extends better to more types. Also would be a hard compile error if you introduce a new type, which is probably a better approach.

---

Whether this is better or worse than a traits class is I think a matter of preference and depends on the rest of your project.

Comment: I hadn't known of `std::conditional`, which sounds very nice in conjunction with a local type alias (`using`).  `mpl::map` is worth knowing about but is probably overkill here.

Comment: @davidbak It's the first thing I thought of, but seems like the worst option when additionally considering `mpl::map` and Yakk's two solutions.

Comment: Gee, I see you had an alias template too and I didn't even notice.  Sign of good syntax, I guess, when you just understand what's meant and it looks totally natural...

Comment: thanks for your answer `std::conditional`, but I gave the checkmark to Yakk because the tag system in his answer is just sweet.